# EventReceivers for sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'd like to register EventReceivers for sites. Currently, I have only for personal folder.
The query I'm using looks like this
https://{{SharePointTenantName}}-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jim_aaa_com/_api/web/getList('/personal/jim_aaa_com/Documents')/EventReceivers

What will be the equivalent for sites. Let's say it's called site1
I'm trying this, but get error
https://{{SharePointTenantName}}.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/_api/web/getList('/sites/site1/Documents')/EventReceivers

I tried to register for events on sites and failed to do so
Succeeded in registering for personal folder

Comment: Did you try the workaround posted below?

Answer (score 0):

You should try with list name, and not relative URL.

```
https://{{SharePointTenantName}}.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/EventReceivers
```

I just test on a list (with full control permissions) and it's working fine.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.